# When installing Postgis it detects wrong postgres version

Tags: postgresql, centos7, postgis

I am working on a Centos7 server.
I have PostGres version 15 installed and running.

Now I am trying to install postgis 3.2.
I get the following error:

```
checking PostgreSQL version... PostgreSQL 9.2.24
configure: error: PostGIS requires PostgreSQL >= 9.6
```

Psql --version gives:
`psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24`

I don't have any installed files for this version. And I cannot stop it since there is no service for this version.

Here's the output of `SELECT VERSION();`

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                 version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 15.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

HELP PLEASE :(

Comment: Make sure that you don't have multiple versions installed.

Comment: "I don't have any installed files for this version"  Obviously you do, or you would not be getting that output.  The first step to fixing the problem is to acknowledge reality.

Comment: What I mean by "no installed files for 9.2" is that there is only on directory `15` for PostgreSQL 15 in `/var/lib/pgsql` directory.
`[pgsql]# ls
15`
Now what I want is to get rid of the 9.2 version

Comment: To repeat this `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24` says there are installed files for 9.2. This `/var/lib/pgsql/15` says there is a Postgres 15 cluster that has been created. The lack of `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2` means no cluster has been created. It is not an indication that 9.2 has not been installed.  You will need to undo whatever install procedure you used to add Postgres 9.2 to your system.

Comment: I am working on a server for the first time. I don't know when or how the 9.2 version was installed. When I search for postgresql9.2 files I obtain them only in `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-9.2.24/`